# Как заполнить большим количеством значений std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11

Как можно осуществить заполнение std::initializer_list большим количеством значений? К примеру мне нужно сделать так:

```
std::initializer_list<int> MyList = {1, 2, 3, ... , 100000};
```

Где `...` означает все целые числа от 4 до 99999 включительно.

Comment: Зачем? В том смысле, что это точно не XY-проблема?...

Comment: @Harry у меня есть шаблонная функция, которая проверяет аргумент типа T на наличие во втором аргументе типа std::initializer_list<T>. И мне требуется создать такой список, в котором будет большое количество элементов. Вопрос именно в том как это сделать в С++

Comment: Мне это все кажется нецелевым использованием `initializer_list`. Он нужен в первую очередь разработчикам контейнеров, чтобы их можно было конструировать из красивого списка в фигурных скобках. В функцию лучше передавать вектор или пару итераторов.

Comment: Возможно, вопрос про [std::iota()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такое

```
int a[100000];
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) a[i] = i+1;
initializer_list<int> MyList(a,a+100000);
```

сработает в VC++, но меня терзают обоснованные сомнения, что другие компиляторы пошлют далеко - и будут правы :)

Возможно, есть какая-то шаблонная красота, но я ее не придумал, да и не очень старался, так как слабо верится, что такое количество - 100000 - компилятор обработает беспроблемно.

И все же - почему-то мне кажется, что если знать вашу изначальную задачу - ее можно решить проще, чем хитрым созданием массива из 100000 `int`ов...

Comment: Возможно, я уже задавал вопрос по реализации функции для которой как раз-таки потребовалось создание такого списка. Сейчас задам ещё один, может что-то прояснится :)

Comment: Не зря сомневаетесь. :) [Мануал говорит](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list), есть только конструктор без параметров. А ТС действительно чем-то странным занимается...

Answer (score 1):

`std::initializer_list` не предназначен для того, чтобы его заполняли динамически. В основном, он используется в конструкторах, которые принимают несколько аргументов одного типа. А `std::initializer_list`, в свою очередь, является легкой оберткой над этими аргументами. Максимум, как вы должны его использовать это `foo = {1, 2, 3};` Если у вас функция принимает последовательность, которую вы не можете или не хотите писать вручную, вам нужно использовать какой-нибудь контейнер (vector) или пару итераторов на начало и конец последовательности.